# NIntegrate with AdaptiveMonteCarlo method

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics, warning-messages, syntax

I have some complicated function that depends on a few parameters that I need to integrate. It is integrated in the fastest way by using "AdaptiveMonteCarlo" method. However, I have found that for some parameters it fails to integrate:

> NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand has evaluated to non-numerical values
> for all sampling points in the region with boundaries ({0.4   1}  {0.98464    1})

A common property of these parameters is that the available integration space is small.

The issue is resolved by changing the method to "MonteCarlo". The results of the integration are trustable. A problem is that the last method is three times slower.

Could you please tell me what may be a reason for this problem with "AdaptiveMonteCarlo"?

P.S. I understand that for the reasonable answer the function and the integral are required. However, the function is really complicated and includes an interpolated function for which a large dataset is used.

Comment: You should read the documentation on [NIntegrate Integration Strategies](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html). I'm not sure if it's the reason but it states: _"AdaptiveMonteCarlo" does not use singularity flattening, and does not have detectors for slow convergence and noisy integration._ . You probably have a singularity in there.

Comment: The message should mean that your integrand `f[x, y]` evaluated to non-numerical values when `0.4 < x < 1` and `0.98464 < y < 1`. Have you checked what you get at such points?

Comment: @MichaelE2: Yes, it is fine. The points are random.

Comment: I don't understand "the point are random." It has nothing to do with what I was asking.  (The randomness has to do with the integration method, not with whether the function evaluates to a number.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 : I mean, parameters for which the integral gives errors.